# Can We Run Solace Appliance Without HBA

Tags: solace, solace-mq

Is it possible to run Solace appliance (3560) without HBA_Card

Pleas help.

Answer (score 2):

Solace Systems do sell appliances without Host Bus Adapters (HBA).
However, these appliances can only perform Direct Messaging, as they are also not equipped with Assured Delivery Blades.

If you own an Solace appliance with a HBA, then you should connect the appliance to a storage area network(SAN) if you wish to perform guaranteed messaging.
While it is possible to use the internal disk for basic tests, the internal disk is extremely limited in size, and only provides a simple RAID 1 redundancy for critical message data. Furthermore, a guaranteed delivery redundant pair cannot be setup without the use of an external disk array.

Comment: Does ADB Card is necessary if we have HBA in Appliance  and using the internal disk not SAN ?

Comment: Yes. ADB is necessary if you want guaranteed messaging.